# How to solve this problem starting new Opera-windows on dual monitor-setup?

Tags: opera

I use Opera and have a setup with two monitors. If I want to open a new URL `opera -newwindow URL`. The outcome differs, if I execute this command in a program on the same screen where Opera is, or on the other.

On the same screen everything is fine. I get the message `opera: Activated running instance` and the new window with the URL is opened.

On the other screen, I get a dialog with the following message: `It appears another opera instance is using the same configuration directory because its lock file is active: /home/(my name)/.opera/lock` and the URL is not shown.

That's not only from console, also if I click a link in E-Mail or so. How can I fix this?

Window-manager is awesome, if it does make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera stores it's profiles in ~/.opera ---

You could be able to run opera in a terminal or create a **script** by disabling the file lock - it's not really a biggie since we'll be disabling the mail database.

```
mv /home/username/.opera/lock ../; opera -pd /home/username/.opera/ -newwindow -nomail; mv ~/lock /home/username/.opera
```

(which handles moving the lock file back again)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. This works with minor modifications. I added -nosession to the opera-commandline (because otherwise it asked) and dropped -newwindow, as otherwise it opened an empty window first.